# SSH to a public account which is forced to run a PHP script. What additional security measures do I need to take?

Tags: linux, php, ssh

I have an Ubuntu server with a user "demo". The user has been setup to run a php script on login with `usermod demo -s /path/to/php/script.php`. The password for the demo account will be public, so anyone can use it.

The PHP script does various things, but for the purposes of this post let's say it echoes "hello friend\n", and then listens for input and if it sees the word "error" then it sends me an email.

So, if I type `ssh demo@server.com`, I get "hello friend" back and then I can type things. If I type something that includes the word "error", I get an email.

How could this be abused at a system/os level? (I feel comfortable with the application level security, e.g. sanitizing input before parsing it in PHP). As far as I can tell, there would be no way for anyone to break out of the PHP script to do anything on the server, which is my main concern. Everything I've tried that results in the PHP script exiting also terminates the SSH connection.

Comment: I mean there are always things like buffer overflow or a bug in PHP that treats certain strings (say strings with null characters) in a certain way, or even a ctrl-c at just the right time during login (these are all guesses, none may work). Always something to worry about :)

Comment: I'd sandbox the account in a container or jail. Map just the filesystem parts it needs access to. Look up [restricted shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) options to get more clues.

Comment: Or just use Docker?...

Comment: Simply (D}DOS your php script

Comment: Rate-limit the script execution. Also you should keep track of how many connections are open, since you can have an attacker open a new connection per second without ever dropping the previous ones, so maybe add a timeout & limit the maximum number of parallel executions